# Angular calling Spring Boot index.html

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have created a web application with a angular front end and a spring boot backend. I currently have my login using OAuth2 with Google, Github and Facebook. Currently my login page is the index.html in spring boot. I am not certain how to move this out of spring and use a angular login component. So I was going to try to just call the spring boot index.html when clicking on a login button in my angular app. How do I make a call to pull up my index.html from spring boot? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

login.component.html

```
<div>
  <button onClick="getLoginPage()" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</div>
<div>
    <button onClick="logout()" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</button>
</div>
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpErrorResponse} from "@angular/common/http";
import {LoginService} from "../../service/login.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginPage = '';

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLoginPage();
  }

  public getLoginPage(): void {
    this.loginService.getLoginPage().subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        this.loginPage = response;
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

login.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from "../../environments/environment";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
  private apiServerUrl = environment.apiBaseUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getLoginPage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>( this.apiServerUrl);
  }
}
```

Controller.java

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "/resources/static/index.html";
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you are trying to go with Angular as Front End and Spring Boot as backend. So I think it's good if you go as UI doing REST calls to backend.

```
@PostMapping(path = "your/path", consumes = "application/json", produces = 
"application/json")
 public ResponseEntity<AuthDTO> login(@RequestBody LoginDTO loginRequest, 
 HttpServletRequest request) {

    // Login logic 
    return new ResponseEntity<AuthDTO>(authResponse, HttpStatus.OK);

 }
```

Comment: @Ryan, did this work?